# Why am I getting wrong answer for this Q

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 12 books on a shelf. In how many ways can we select at least one of them .

So , I wrote the answer as 12C1. This means that selecting 1 book out of 12 books.

But it is $2^{12 }- 1$. Please help in this.

Comment: By selecting "at least 1," it means you are allowed to select 2.  Or 3. Any nonzero number of books that you want.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot. This was a major mistake I was making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that at least 1 means that you can chose any value $\ge 1$, so, it's just $$\sum_{n=1}^{12}\binom{12}{n}$$ which can be written as $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{12}\binom{12}{n}\right)-\binom{12}{0}$$ which would be $2^{12}-1$

Comment: Can you please simplify the way you have written ? I don’t know about sigma and matrices sir

Comment: $\binom{a}{b}$ is the same as a choose b, and sigma has been explained by 5201314

Comment: $\binom{12}{k}$ what does this mean in your answer . I didn’t understand this

Comment: @user15072279 The big sigma is just a sum. So, for instance, $\sum_{i=1}^{10}{i} = 1 + 2 + \text{ ... } + 10$. And $\binom{n}{x} = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$; it’s what you called “nCx”.

Comment: Ok. I got sigma meaning . Not 12 and below it is written k. That’s it. @Gauss .even in asv answer , he has written only a_k which is easy to understand than $\binom{12}{k}$.

Comment: Well, see, I've written the n (I used n instead of k, doesn't make a difference) below the 12 means that I am summing all the values of 12 choose n as n goes from 1 to 12. So, $\sum_{n=1}^{12}\binom{12}{n}$ means finding the value of 12c1+12c2+12c3+...+12c11+12c12. The other user who answered has given the way the value is found

Comment: @Asv Why would you add all the selections but . 12c1 + 12c2.?

Answer (score 1):

"At least one of them" means that we can select $1,2,3,4,\cdots,12$ books as opposed to just 1. So the number of ways can be found by $$\sum_{k=1}^{12}\binom{12}{k}$$
Consider the binomial theorem: $$(1+r)^{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}r^k$$
In the case of $r=1$, we have $$2^{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}$$
So the required number of ways is $$\sum_{k=1}^{12}\binom{12}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}-\binom{12}{0}=2^{12}-1$$

Note: if you are not familiar with sigma notation, note that $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k=a_0+a_1+\cdots +a_n$$